# Автоматизация сборки проекта

Tags: c#, wpf, автоматизация

Есть желание автоматизировать рутинный процесс подготовки приложения для дальнейшего создания инсталяционного пакета.

Нужно установить версию в файле AssemblyInfo.cs базируясь на сегодняшней дате. Собрать решение. Скопировать часть файлов из папки Release (или удалить часть файлов в этой папке и скопировать все, что осталось). Скопировать часть файлов из другого места. Также перед копированием новых файлов нужно удалить старые. И запускаться всё это должно одним скриптом (bat файл, например).

Пока остановился на таком варианте - есть 2 утилиты и один батник. Первая утилита обновляет версию в файле AssemblyInfo.cs, вторая - копирует файлы. В батнике запускается первая утилита, потом компилируется решение через MSBuild, после чего вторая утилита копирует файлы.

Comment: Да, это можно делать батником или powershell-скриптом. Или с помощью [MSBuild](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild?view=vs-2019). Также можете посмотреть [Nuke](https://nuke.build/) и [Cake](https://cakebuild.net/) - это системы сборки на языке C#.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov а где бы про батник или powershell почитать, желательно с примером. Отдельные средства пока не планирую подключать.

Comment: Хотя вы и не планируете пока другие средства (например, посмотреть в сторону сборочного сервера, скажем, teamcity) лучше выбирать текущие способы решения таким образом, чтобы потом при подключении этих самых других средств не пришлось переделывать весь проект. Так что я бы порекомендовал MSBuild, а не батники. Видите ли, CI/DI и сборочные сервера -- это современный мейнстрим, вам когда надоест сидеть в каменном веке с батниками или придёте на работу, где всё это нужно -- всё равно придётся с этим разбираться.

Comment: Автоматическое изменение версии можно сделать например расширением [Automatic Versions 2](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PrecisionInfinity.AutomaticVersions). Копирование и прочие действия после сборки можно сделать через post-build действия в параметрах.

Comment: Я вам советую Azure DevOps, отличная вещь от Microsoft. которая может кучу всего. Ну то есть, ваш проект как не крути надо гдет хранить, чтоб в случае чего, вы могли его восстановить, архивы и прочее - старый век, нужен GIT. Ну так почему бы не сделать так, что при каждой отправке кода в GIT, у вас выполнялся бы ваш сценарий сборки и публикации?